# Show offline hosts as OK

Tags: printer, icinga2

In Icingaweb2 I'd like to **show some unreachable hosts as OK (green)**, while only performing dependent checks on each of these hosts when the respective host is available.

Some background:
I'm using Icinga2 with IcingaWeb2 in our company. I have successfully configured Icinga to monitor some servers. Now I'd also like to use Icinga to monitor some **desktop PCs** and **printers**.

PCs and printers are switched on and off by our employees at will. So if a PC or printer is switched off, that's perfectly fine. There should not be any warning about that in IcingaWeb2.

However, if the PC or printer is switched on, I'd like to gather some telemetry about how much disk space is available on that PC or how much ink is left in the printer and other things like that. I'd also like to get a warning or critical notification if something is wrong.

So my question is, how I can configure Icinga2 in such a way, if there is any at all.

So far I have unsuccessfully tried:

- Having the host always show up as OK, by doing this:
  Settings `check_command` for the host to `dummy`
  This always showed the host as OK, but I still needed some failing service for the dependency, which would show up in red. If I could hide the result of that service in IcingaWeb2, my problem would be solved.
- Disabling notifications. This does not seem to have any influence on IcingaWeb2. So far, I'm not using notifications to their full potential, so this is probably going to be important for me in the future, but not now.

One option would be to use passive checks. That would mean, that I would be leaving much of the Icinga2 infrastructure behind, for I would have to configure some other daemon to do the checks and then deliver the results to Icinga2. That would bring me into conflict with the DRY principle, so I'm trying to avoid that. However, if you have some thought about that, I'd be glad to hear it.